# Can Ubuntu be installed on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus Verizon 4g phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am an old man who is interested in seeing the Ubuntu OS used more widely. I read the instructions for flashing the OS onto a Samsung Galaxy Nexus cell phone. I ordered such a phone. When it came I started to follow the instructions on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install?action=show&redirect=TouchInstallProcess
I watched a couple of YouTube videos to guide me through the process. One video featured a young man who looked like he knew what he was talking about. He said that the Samsung phone had to be a "GSM" something, which the Verizon 4G model is not.

I have three questions:

1. Must the Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone indeed be a "GSM" in order to accept the Ubuntu OS?
2. If yes, could the instructions be made clearer to indicate this fact, as well as any other facts that civilians (as opposed to professional developers) might need to know in order to flash the OS onto a phone?
3. If yes again, does anyone want to buy a slightly used Samsung Galaxy Nexus Verizon 4G cell phone cheap?

Thanks.

~George

Answer (score 0):

According to the page, only the codenames `maguro` is supported.  You can find out what your device codename is by using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en) from the Play store.

It is not entirely mandatory that the phone be GSM, just that the OS images that you receive will be specifically for GSM and if you flash it onto your non-GSM phone, it might not work entirely.

You can flash an [unofficial ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2159515) that someone created for their non-GSM GNex, but it might not work and may not be a straightforward process.  It is worth reading through the thread if you decide to go down this route.  You should familiarize yourself with Nandroid, ClockworkMod and the commandline for this - in case the results aren't what you want, you will need to flash your original OS back or flash an alternate like CyanogenMod.

I have submitted a change to the wiki page indicating 'GSM/HSPA+', pending approval.